# How can I use a regex to match multiple address lines?

Tags: java, regex

Given the following example text, can I use a regex to match each line of each address, and to add markers to know when one address finishes and the next begins? At present, I know how to match each entire address. I could then run a second regex to pick out the individual lines, but is it possible to achieve both these steps in one go?

```
Address:
Address 1 line 1,
Address 1 line 2,
Address 1 line 3

Address:
Address 2 line 1,
Address 2 line 2,
Address 2 line 3,
Address 2 line 4

Address:
Address 3 line 1,
Address 3 line 2
```

Comment: Use `Matcher#appendReplacement`

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, I had not known about that method. However, I am still working on how it could be used to pick out the address lines. It appears to be a method to replace matches with a specified string, and still needs a regex to match each address line.

Comment: I am sorry, I have no idea how to help you as the final output is unclear to me.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `Pattern` with the `DOTALL` flag on, enabling to find through multiple lines, using the `"Address:"` string as a delimiter:

```
// for test
String addresses = "Address:" + System.getProperty("line.separator")
        + "Address 1 line 1," + System.getProperty("line.separator")
        + "Address 1 line 2," + System.getProperty("line.separator")
        + "Address 1 line 3"
        + "Address:" + System.getProperty("line.separator")
        + "Address 2 line 1," + System.getProperty("line.separator")
        + "Address 2 line 2," + System.getProperty("line.separator")
        + "Address 2 line 3";
//                           | look behind for "Address:"
//                           |            | any 1+ character, 
//                           |            | reluctantly quantified
//                           |            |  | lookahead for "Address:"
//                           |            |  | or end of input
//                           |            |  |            | dot can mean
//                           |            |  |            | line separator
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=Address:).+?(?=Address:|$)", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(addresses);
// iterating matches within given string, and printing
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.printf("Found: %s%n%n", m.group());
}
```

**Output**

```
Found: 
Address 1 line 1,
Address 1 line 2,
Address 1 line 3

Found: 
Address 2 line 1,
Address 2 line 2,
Address 2 line 3
```

**Note**

In order to exclude the line separator after your `"Address:"` token from the match, you can use this refined pattern:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=Address:"
    + System.getProperty("line.separator")+").+?(?=Address:"
    + System.getProperty("line.separator")+"|$)", 
    Pattern.DOTALL
);
```

Comment: Thank you Mena. If I understand your post correctly, your regex matches twice, once for the Address 1 lines and again for the Address 2 lines. However, what I want is for each address line (i.e. Address 1 line 1, Address 1 line 2 etc) to be a match, to keep the lines separate from each other.

Answer (score 0):

If regex is what you want...

If you have a limited number of lines in an address (in your example 4), you could grab them with:

```
Address:\s*?(?:\n(.*),)?(?:\n(.*),)?(?:\n(.*),)?(?:\n(.*),)?(?:\n(.*))
```

Here the text `Address:` marks the beginning of the block and the four lines are grabbed, with the first three being optional.

(You'll need the global flags.)

[regex101 example](https://regex101.com/r/nL1mQ0/1).

Comment: ClasG, thank you but yes, unfortunately I need a solution that applies to a list of addresses where the maximum number of address lines is not known in advance by the program.